# Ellipsis in table cell is showing through overlying dom element

Tags: html, css, dom

I found a strange issue when adding `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the cells in table:

It seems like the `ellipsis` ignores the `z-index` and shows it *through* the overlying dom element when moving the overlying element on top of the table.

This is the dom structure:

```
<div>
  Could be a taskbar
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>uno</th>
      <th>dos</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the css:

```
div{
  background: rgb(200, 100, 100);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}

div:hover{
  top: 0;
}

table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

table thead tr th{
  background: rgb(100, 200, 100);
  width: 100px;
}

table tbody tr td{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the default view: ("taskbar" `top` is `-50px`)

[image]

This is the "issue" view: ("taskbar" `top` is `0`)

[image]

Live-test: https://jsfiddle.net/gu1x1eka/

Notice the dots of the ellipsis.

- Tested on Firefox 45.0.2 [fails!]
- Tested on Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m [works!]

Do you have the same issue? Is a mistake in my css causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `z-index: 1;` on the taskbar `div`.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44dqcnxh/)

Reference to this issue (added per OP's request): http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201305/firefox_and_the_magical_text-overflowellipsis_z-index/

Comment: The question is: Why do I have to add z-index? Are ellipsis a new dom element?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 43.0.1 and it was working (not showing the ellipsis). Updating to 45.0.2 now. EDIT: Still works in 45.0.2.

Comment: @Maurice Doesn't seem like a new DOM element (can't see it in inspector), but I'm not entirely sure why Firefox needs `z-index` to be added here. Chalk it up to browser quirk?

Comment: nevermind. Setting a z-index seems to solve this problem in **firefox**. Add this to your answer: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201305/firefox_and_the_magical_text-overflowellipsis_z-index/